# Limit one row per unique column value selecting by max column value

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to select the most recent `WorkOrder` for each `Customer`. I've used `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY`, but the result returned is not the newest `WorkOrder`.

**Table Structure:**

```
WorkOrder
    id
    customer_id
    create_date
    ...
```

**Sample Data:**

```
WorkOrder.id    WorkOrder.customer_id   WorkOrder.create_date   ...
1               1                       2012-01-01 12:00:00
2               1                       2016-06-29 12:00:00
3               2                       2015-05-05 12:00:00
```

**Desired Result:**

```
WorkOrder.id    WorkOrder.customer_id   WorkOrder.create_date   ...
2               1                       2016-06-29 12:00:00
3               2                       2015-05-05 12:00:00
```

**Current Code:**

```
$query = DB::table('WorkOrder')
    ->orderBy('WorkOrder.create_date', 'desc')
    ->groupBy('WorkOrder.customer_id');

// select * from `WorkOrder` group by `WorkOrder`.`customer_id` order by `WorkOrder`.`create_date` desc
```

**Current Result:**

```
WorkOrder.id    WorkOrder.customer_id   WorkOrder.create_date   ...
1               1                       2012-01-01 12:00:00
3               2                       2015-05-05 12:00:00
```

Comment: you're using `group by`, whichmeans that non-grouped fields can be returned in any order. mysql generally returns the FIRST value it encounters, even if that's not from the same row that the grouped-by fields get their values from.

Comment: So nix the `group by`? How do I limit it to one result per `customer_id`?

Comment: can't do it as single simple query. you need a subquery to get the IDs of the rows you want, then an outer query to fetch the entire row for those ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use max function

```
SELECT WorkOrder.id, WorkOrder.customer_id, MAX(WorkOrder.create_date) FROM `WorkOrder` GROUP BY `WorkOrder`.`customer_id` ORDER BY `WorkOrder`.`create_date` DESC
```

Comment: How does this even work? The GROUP BY does not correspond with the SELECT.

Comment: it will group by result on customer id and give the max created date value

Comment: What happens to the WorkOrder.id? In ANSI SQL this should generate an error.

Comment: @Grayson The query is working for me. Removing the `GROUP BY` clause breaks it.

Comment: @Shane It must be something in MySQL. customer_id is not repeated? I was not suggesting removing the GROUP BY.

Comment: @Grayson `WorkOrder.customer_id` is indeed repeated throughout the rows.

Comment: @Shane if its working and you accept it as answer then mark it as answer else it will show this question as unanswered question

Comment: @Shane This explains the it: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @MaheshMadushanka still testing to make sure.

Comment: @Shane If customer_id is repeating, then that is NOT what you want, right? You wanted distinct customer_ids.

Comment: @Grayson Correct. Only the most recent `WorkOrder` for each `WorkOrder.customer_id`.

Comment: @Grayson I misunderstood what you were asking, but the results given by this query do not have repeated `customer_id`s.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM WorkOrder 
WHERE (customer_id, create_date) IN 
      (SELECT customer_id, MAX(create_date) FROM WorkOrder
       GROUP By customer_id)
ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: @Shane have you tested this yet?

Comment: The query took a few minutes to run. Mahesh's is virtually instant.

Comment: @Shane is there an index on customer_id?

Comment: (I didn't create this schema) There is an autoincrementing primary key `Customer.id` field and a unique `Customer.customer_id` field. `WorkOrder.customer_id` isn't foreign keyed. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @Shane Interesting. I am not familiar with MySQL. I am surprised that the query is taking so long unless it is because there is not an index. Are the results correct?

Comment: The results are correct. It probably does have to do with the index since none of these tables have any.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select wo.*
from workorder wo
where create_date = (select max(wo2.create_date)
                     from workorder wo2
                     where wo2.customer_id = wo.customer_id
                    );
```

That advantage to this approach over using a `group by` in the subquery:

- If you have other filters in the `where` clause, then this will only look up the values on a reduced set of rows.
- It can use an index for the lookup, without having to first do an aggregation.

Comment: Can you construct a scenario in which it runs faster than the equivalent uncorrelated version? In my tests, it never has.

Comment: This query is taking a considerable amount of time compared to Mahesh's. I'll do some testing with my other `WHERE` clauses to see if they line up in the end.

Comment: @Shane It processing every row in the table and executing the subquery for each row. This is going to be slow.

Comment: @Grayson . . . It won't be slow with an index on `workorder(customer_id, create_date)`.  In fact, it should be considerably faster than aggregating the entire result set.